# How does McPherson know Helena G. Wells?

Tags: warehouse-13

In the beginning of Season 2 of Warehouse 13 (Episode 201. *Time will tell*), Leena posing as Claudia debronzes H.G. Wells. And afterwards Wells (with a blanket over her head) is seen exiting the Warehouse along with  McPherson, and he says:

> 'Come on, old friend'

This would imply that they know each other, but H.G. Wells was bronzed in 1899. McPherson would've been born at the 1930's at most (I am taking as a reference the age of the actor who plays it. Which is Roger Rees who was born in 1944). So, how exactly do they know each other?

Comment: Maybe she was temporarily debronzed when the first Mrs. F died and her sister took over as Caretaker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, Jack Kenny (a.k.a writer of *Time Will Tell* and EP of Warehouse 13) was kind enough to answer my question on twitter, here's his answer

> [@MonseFoster](https://twitter.com/MonseFoster) "old
>   friend" is a phrase I've heard Brits use as term of
>   endearment. Not necessarily literal.
>
> — Jack Kenny
>   (@Bumpynight) [August 6, 2014](https://twitter.com/Bumpynight/statuses/497108557608005633)

So, that means they did not know each other, although there's gotta be a reason why McPherson chose H.G as partner-in-crime.

Comment: That was awesome of him. +1 to Jack (and to you). So maybe Helena DID have a sort of Long Game planned, after all she had part of her super weapon stashed in her beloved Christina's crypt!! AND bronzed people can be talked to without debronzing them - as Steve did with Claudia when Paracelsus bronzed her - so maybe H.G. & McPhe had an agreement of sorts....